# Alternative (non-gematria) explanations of the "remove his teeth" line

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, four-sons

Are there any alternative answers historically given as to why the Hagadah (page 8 of [this](http://www.chabad.org/media/pdf/43/SsGl439147.pdf)) says to remove the wicked son's teeth, besides the usual gematria answer?

Related: [Source of the "remove his teeth" gematria](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36816/source-of-the-remove-his-teeth-gematria)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Rebbe Rashab](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/272209/jewish/Rabbi-Sholom-DovBer-Schneersohn.htm) has a kabbalistic answer to this, in that don't read it as teeth, rather as the letter shin. By removing the Shin from רשע, you leave the רע, and cut off its source in holiness that lets it exist.

The [Abarbanel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10956&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=) explains that it means he is making himself as a foreigner, so take away his eating of the Korban Pesach - hit his ability to use his teeth.

But the plain meaning is likely an allusion to Yirmiyahu [31:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16028/jewish/Chapter-31.htm#v=28&showrashi=true) and Yechezkel [18:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16116/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#showrashi=true&v=2). The Abarbanel makes the association but doesn't quite explain how it works.

Comment: Is there a specific person that writes that this is a reference to Yirmiyahu and Yechezkel?

Comment: @AvramLevitt, The Abarbanel, as I wrote.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was unrelated to the Abarbanel (a third answer). Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In the hagadda attributed to the Malbim - just as your teeth are blunted from that which you feed yourself, you put the food in your mouth which blunts your teeth, so too you answer the Rasha from his own message - he said "for you" (and did not include himself), so too you respond to him by saying "for me and not for him"

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple explanation is that since the wicked son is only using his mouth to speak cynically, we should prevent him from continuing to speak.

Comment: Source? I'm looking for historical answers to this, not a fresh dvar torah.

Comment: I described what "I think [is] the simple explanation", not a dvar torah, such as the wonderful ones brought by Avram Levitt, Backseat Chazan and Yishai.

Comment: @Ypnypn then this should be a comment.  The question asks for historically given answers.

Comment: @YEZ The word "historically" was just added to the question.

Comment: @Ypnypn Sorry, I see that now.  Nonetheless, your answer has (unfortunately) become a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why knock out his teeth specifically and not any other punishment? Since he counted himself out and refuses to eat *Matzah*, Why does he need teeth!?

> ואף אתה הקהה את שניו: למה דוקא הקהת השינים ולא עונש אחר אלא לפי שרשע זה
>   הוציא את עצמו מן הכלל ואינו רוצה לאכול מצה  אם־כן, שינים למה לו ?‏

[From נרות שבת No. 102](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_28549_5.pdf)

Comment: Why is it assumed that he refuses to eat matzah?

Comment: @avramlevitt hmmm not sure

Comment: @avramlevitt, he is rejecting the "avodah" which is the Mitzvos of the night. Matza is the only one that is still Min HaTorah today.